# разница во времени между юзером и сайтом

Tags: php

есть вывод даты добавления новости (date()) на сайте, но если допустим у человека разница во времени -6 часов, и я добавлю новость 5 числа в час ночи, а у человека зашедшего на сайт будет ещё 4 число и увидит дату добавления новости и  будет в непонимании, как можно исправить это?

Comment: На сайте все временные метки следует хранить во времени по Гривничу UTC. Дальше идут варианты: 1. На стороне клиента javscript код преобразовывает это время для каждого сообщения/новости в соответствии с часовым поясом указанным у клиента в системе. 2. Пользователь при регистрации или первом заходе на сайт указывает свой часовой пояс (сохраням в куки например) и в дальнейшем php при генерации страницы пересчитывает отображаемое время в соответствии с указанным часовым поясом (на стороне сервера). 3. По ip определяем регион проживания пользователя и на сервере пересчитываем время.

Answer (score 2):

При загрузке сайта напиши JS код который создает Cookie в котором хранит часовой пояс пользователя. Благодоря чему в backend-е при любом запросе ты будешь получать часовой пояс.

Если тебе нужен текущий часовой пояс пользователя то - после входа пользователя ты читаешь куки и если оно есть то сравниваешь с текушим значением часового пояса пользователя в БД - если есть изменения - изменяешь.

Данное решение хорошо тем что ты всегда знаешь текущий часовой пояс! Например когда пользователь изменить часовой пояс - ему хватит просто войти в сайт и обновлеяния сядут в БД.